# Undefined when trying to get root scope of one Angular app by another in Chrome and FF

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When trying to take hold of the root Angular scope in a newly opened child window (with a separate angular application) I receive undefined in Chrome and FF.

**Example:**

```
var childWindowRootApp = childWindowRefeference.angular.element(childWindowRefeference.document.querySelector('[data-ng-app="mainApp"]'));
var rootScope = childWindowRootApp.scope(); // rootScope variable undefined here
```

Same code works without any glitch in IE10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try manually calling the bootstrap() method on the angular in the child window **before** calling scope():

```
childWindowRefeference.angular.bootstrap(childWindowRefeference.document, ["yourApp"]);
```